# Set selected option NOT based on v-model

Tags: vuejs2

I have a select with `v-model`, but I need to set the selected option based on other values.

Is it possible?

This is what I've tried:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="product.category">
                <option v-for="(c, index) in categories" :value="c.id" :selected="product.category.id == c.id" :key="index">
                    {{ c.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

However, `:selected` seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the `v-model` from

```
 v-model="product.category"
```

to

```
v-model="product.category.id"
```

and remove

```
:selected="product.category.id == c.id"
```

You can read more about [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html).

Comment: That would be my last resort ас that would requirе additional changes to the API which I am hoping to avoid.

Comment: Could you update with the question with `data` option in your component? Or create jsfiddle?